# How to calculate the error of percentages

Tags: standard-deviation, standard-error, proportion

Is it correct to calculate the standard deviation of percentages/proportions as you would for four numbers (i.e. non-percentages)?

---

Thanks for your help @user2974951  @whuber and @asdf. Yes, you're right I was alluding to using the common SD formula. To explain further, my four percentages are from an experiment where we measured the uptake of a chemical by 4 plants. Each plant took up between 40% and 55% of what was applied, therefore the percentage can't ever be >100%. So, if I understand correctly I will need to use the proportion SD which is different to the common SD formula? Thanks for the link to the thread @user2974951

Comment: Yes. 55% is just 0.55. You can also think in absolute numbers: 1st plant ate 55 g, 2nd 52 g, etc., out of 100 g applied. On average, they ate 53.7 g. Each had the same amount to begin with (100 g), so the average proportion is 53.7/100 = 0.537 = 53.7%.

Comment: Thanks corey979. I guess the question I was wondering is, can you calculate the standard deviation of these four percentages? Or would that be statistically incorrect?

Comment: @Andrew You can do that, as for whether it is sensible is another matter. SD is really only sensible when you have a normally distributed variable. In your case that seems to be the case.

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.

Comment: @user2974951 SD makes sense, period.  It's just a statistic and has nothing inherently to do with normality.

Comment: @whuber But how would you interpret a SD for say a (highly) skewed distribution? It wouldn't have much meaning.

Comment: @user2974951 It might or might not--but that's not the question being discussed here.  Indeed, you can find the formula $\sqrt{p(1-p)}$ for the SD of a proportion in every elementary textbook, even though unless $p=1/2$ the distribution of the proportion will be skewed.  Are you proposing throwing out all of elementary statistics?  (Just joking, of course.)

Comment: @whuber Yes that would work, however as I understood OP asked about calculating the SD `as you would for four numbers (i.e. non-percentages)` alluding to using the common SD formula used for normal distributions. In this case the normal SD could return nonsensical intervals. In conclusion Andrew, use the proportion SD formula provided by whuber.

Comment: @user2974951 That "common SD formula" is not for Normal distributions: it applies to any distribution whatsoever.  Please note that the $\sqrt{p(1-p)}$ formula is just a special case.  The thread at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/284160 has much more to say about this.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If you are just expressing a number that can take any value as a percent (for example, relative growth of number of sales), then go ahead! -15% is just -0.15, 133% is just 1.33 and so on.

However, if what you're dealing with is a proportion (as in "73% of students passed the test, ie: a value between 0% and 100%), then you should calculate standard deviation from the binomial distribution, in other words, for a population of n and a proportion of p (measured from 0 to 1), your variance is n*p*(1-p), and your standard deviation is the square root of that number

Comment: In the proportion case there might be overdispersion, in which case the binomial standard deviation would be to small.