# What does "properly normalized" mean in CLT?

Tags: central-limit-theorem

What does "properly normalized" mean in CLT?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem

> In probability theory, the central limit theorem (CLT) establishes that, in some situations, when independent random variables are added, **their properly normalized sum** tends toward a normal distribution

Comment: That we divide the sum by the square root of the sample size, or, equivalently, that we scale the average by the square root of the sample size.

Comment: Search: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=central%20limit%20theorem.  In my answer at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/3904/919 I take pains to explain why and exactly how the variables are normalized, especially why the standard deviation (and not some other measure of variance) is critically important.