# CLT application to exponential distribution?

Tags: python, sampling, central-limit-theorem, exponential-distribution

I'm a little confused how the CLT can apply to aggregations of the exponential distribution. It's my understanding that the CLT says, in plain English, "sample *means* from virtually any distribution will tend towards normal." I've seen this demonstrated in the case of rolling a fair, 6-sided die. If single rolls are sampled then the distribution will remain uniform. However, if 2+ rolls were executed per trial, then the resulting distribution will be approximately normal, peaking at 3.5 when n is sufficiently high.

However, I'm trying to replicate this process with the exponential distribution and not finding the result I was expecting.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

samples = []
sample_size = 2
itrs = 10_000
while len(samples) < itrs:
  samples.append(sum(np.random.exponential(scale=1,size=sample_size))/sample_size)

plt.hist(dist,bins=12)
```

[image: exponential histogram]

So either my understanding of the CLT is far off or the [numpy's exponential sampler](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.exponential.html) doesn't behave the way that I had expected. Could someone clarify where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Your sample size of $2$ is scarcely large!  Keep increasing it and study the output.

Comment: The CLT is actually about the limiting distribution of standardized averages or sums *in the limit* as $n\to\infty$, not at any sample size you like. Now you can often see averages or sums start to look pretty close to normal at modest sample sizes, but for exponentials $n=2$ is just not close enough to infinity. If you want averages to look quite close to normal at sample sizes of 2 you need to start fairly close to normal. For some distributions (for which the CLT still works), sample sizes in the billions are not sufficient.

Comment: There's quite a few answers on site that address aspects of this.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/339759/how-can-the-central-limit-theorem-hold-for-distributions-which-have-limits-on-th and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/422870/central-limit-theorem-on-distributions-with-support-other-than-mathbbr