# Why intuitively is standard deviation the correct thing to scale to get Central Limit Theorem?

Tags: variance, standard-deviation, central-limit-theorem, intuition

**Let me start off by saying I already know all the rigorous formulas, but let me explain why I still feel like something is missing in my understanding.** There is **no need** for any answer going over e.g. the variance calculation for sums of i.i.d. random variables! That is **not** what this question is about.

Basically, it comes down to this question in @whuber's amazing answer https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/3904/264044:

> - *What is special about the sum*?  Why don't we have central limit theorems for other mathematical combinations of numbers such as their product or their maximum?  (It turns out we do, but they are not quite so general nor do they always have such a clean, simple conclusion unless they can be reduced to the CLT.)  The sequences of $m_n$ and $s_n$ are not unique but they're *almost* unique in the sense that eventually they have to approximate the expectation of the sum of $n$ tickets and the *standard deviation* of the sum, respectively ...
> - The standard deviation is one measure of the spread of values, but it is by no means the only one nor is it the most "natural," either historically or for many applications.  (Many people would choose something like a [median absolute deviation from the median](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=median+absolute+deviation+MAD), for instance.)
> - *Why does the SD appear in such an essential way?*

More rigorously: we have $S_n$ a sum of i.i.d. $X_n$. For example, we may plot the binomial coefficients (i.i.d. sums of Bernoullis/Rademachers) and notice they seem to have the "same shape" --- in fact more and more like the same shape, once one scales $\tilde S_n:=\frac{S_n-m_n}{s_n}$. Finding what $m_n$ is easy: it's a linear shift, and expectation being linear, everything's fine. Let's just assume the $X_n$ are shifted to be mean $0$.

But now we have to figure out what $s_n$ "keeps the shape". Our idea that it "approaches some limiting shape" is a statement about convergence of distributions of course, and convergence of distributions means in particular all moments will converge/stabilize to some value, and in fact more generally, all $\mathbb E[f(\tilde S_n)]$ should converge/stabilize to some value.

And somehow, all of **all these choices** of $f$, we choose $f(x)=x^2$, and due to some algebraic miracle, things work out perfectly and we see that $s_n$ must be (or at least converge to as $n\to\infty$) some constant multiple of $\sqrt n$.

So basically, from this perspective, we see that $s_n$ is in a sense very fundamental/universal (it's the values that make $\mathbb E[f(\tilde S_n)]$ stabilize for all "nice" $f$), but simply due to some algebraic miracle, it is only for $f(x)=x^2$ that we can compute explicitly the correct asymptotic of $s_n$. So it almost seems like the "2" nature of $s_n \asymp n^{1/2}$ is by accident, but the "universality" of $s_n$ tell us on the other hand that there's nothing on accident about this --- it was completely inevitable.

> **Question:** Can some one shed some light on any deeper reason why $s_n \asymp n^{1/2}$? Perhaps even if one can do the calculation with a different $f$, and see that still $n^{1/2}$ pops out, that would be insightful?

Comment: I appreciate the shout-out, but I am baffled by the question, because I thought I had explicitly addressed it in my CLT post you reference.   In the concluding paragraph I wrote, "This simple approximation, though, suggests how de Moivre might originally have suspected ... that the proper scale factor $s_n$ must be proportional to $\sqrt n$ (as shown by the denominator of the preceding formula)."  Could you therefore please elaborate on what form a "deeper reason" might take?

Comment: @whuber I suppose I am thinking from the point of view that $s_n$ should be universal, in that every $f$ should get you to $\asymp \sqrt n$ (so not exactly the combinatorial point of view in your answer). I am not entirely satisfied with choosing one "magical" $f$ that makes everything work, like $f(x)=x^2$. If $s_n$ is derives from something involving **all** $f$, I would be more satisfied if I could see how $\sqrt n$ must pop out from all $f$ (or if not all, than many $f$), instead of just a few "magically selected/amenable" $f$.

Comment: I don't understand your reference to a "magical $f.$"  My analysis applies to all distributions having finite variances.

Comment: @whuber I am referring to the $f$ in the point of view that all the "statistics" $\mathbb E[f(\tilde S_n)]$ should stabilize, and the $f$ that most easily allows us to calculate what the correct factor $s_n$ is, is $f(x)=x^2$. And furthermore, it seems $f(x)=x^2$ is the only $f$ that allows us to perform this calculation (or perhaps it can be done with say $f(x)=x^4$, but that calculation would depend on the $f(x)=x^2$ calculation, I think?).