Why do the skewness and kurtosis formulae have powers of the variance in the denominator?
We calculate the variance as the centered 2nd moment $E[(X-\mu)^2]$.
So when it comes to the skewness and kurtosis, why are the 3rd and 4th moments divided by the 3rd and 4th powers of $\sigma$? Why not simply use $E[(X-\mu)^3]$ and $E[(X-\mu)^4]$?
Please note I am only beginning to get the hang of things, so my understanding might be on shaky ground.

This is called standardization.  It is so fundamental to statistical thinking that it would be well worth your while to research it.  You could search our site for highly voted answers, for instance.

Yes, thanks for the terminology, I'll look it up!

@whuber, I think it's worth exploring why isn't $\left(\sqrt{E[x^4]}\right)^{1/4}$ used as a scaling factor? I have an idea rooted in physics, but it's not a trivial question

@Aksakal One could use that.  But (a) it's overly limited -- there are practical cases where the second moment exists but the fourth doesn't but, much more importantly, it has a universal role in the CLT, as I attempted to explain at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/3904/919.  Nevertheless, I am intrigued: how would fourth moments arise naturally in physics where second moments would not already suffice?

@whuber sorry for confusion, I meant the second moment being naturally present in physics. CLT is a good argument, of course. I just think there is not enough discussion on why the second moment is used as dispersion metric, and not fourth, for instance

@Aksakal Sorry about my misunderstanding.  The more basic issue -- this comes up frequently -- is why not go all the way and use the absolute first moment for standardization?  That is even better than the second moment in terms of wide applicability.  There are good answers both in terms of OLS regression and the CLT, and a narrower but powerful answer through analysis of the Bivariate Normal distribution (which turns out not to be so special, as my more general treatment at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/71303/919 shows).

Another possibly intuitive reason, is that the mean and standard deviation are both in the units of your variable, and are interpretable as such. Higher order moments are unit-less. So skewness needs to be divided by something which is the cube of your unit. 3rd power of the sd is one way. Note that the CV (mean/sd) can be understood as standardized 2nd moment, and is much more interpretable. after all, a sd of 100 does not tell me much: is that large or small? But a CV of .5 does (it is large). Effect sizes (unit-less) are also standardized to the sd. And thus are higher order moments.

@jginestet Higher moments are definitely not unitless!  For instance, the fourth moment is in the fourth power of the units.  Your reasoning is circular.  One could indeed standardize using, say, the sixth root of the sixth central moment and this would provide alternative measures of skewness and kurtosis (at least for all distributions with finite sixth moments).

@whuber, the question was about standardized moments, which we want to be unitless. The kth central moment has unit of the variable to the kth power. But skweness and kurtosis are "standardized" moments; teh OP asked "why"?

These expressions in terms of several higher order moments appear when you take the determinant of the moment matrix
m0  m1  m2
m1  m2  m3
m2  m3  m4
and so on. these determinants must be positive because  the probability density is positive. They are invariants of this density and this is were you get them most probably

In fact, these are the coefficients of the quadratic form given by the mentioned matrix(s).

This is incorrect: the determinant of that moment matrix obviously does not involve reciprocals of anything.
